# Attribute to mark as "internal use"

Tags: c#

I made a class which requires the public default constructor but
that is never called; instead another constructor is used at DataGrid.AddingNewItem.

I'd like to tell developers that the default constructor is not for their use.
Is there an attribute which suits the purpose?

I had checked DebuggerNonUserCode and MethodImplAttribute with MethodImplAttributes.InternalCall but not sure that's the proper approach.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.dataGrid1.CanUserAddRows = true;
        var list = new List<RowX>();
        this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list);
        this.dataGrid1.AddingNewItem += (s, e) => e.NewItem = new RowX("ABC");
    }
}

public class RowX
{
    public RowX()
    {
        //this is not used. but CollectionView require this to be public or 
        //CanUserAddRows doesn't work.
    }

    public RowX(object o)
    {
        //this is the actual ctor.
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `DataGrid` instead of `DataGridView`? [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests `DataGridView` is a new and improved version of `DataGrid`. Actually it looks like `DataGrid` was removed in .NET 3.5, so you must be using quite an old version of c#

Comment: eh, I mean WPF, System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.
But I've playing with WPF for 7 years also with WinForms for 15 years and I guess I know howtos about them, my question is simply about attribute..

Answer (score 1):

Mark it `private`

```
class Foo
{ 
    private Foo() {}
}
```

Comment: if foo has private constructor, CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List<Foo>) has CanAddNew=false and CandAddNewItem=true which datagrid doesn't allow UI adding. thus I think there's such a situation which requires public default constructor.

Comment: ok i don't know what you're talking about. maybe edit your post with some code illustrating what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can give your constructor an [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

- [`private`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) This means it can only be called from another constructor in that class.

  ```
  public class PrivateClass
  {
      //Only from inside this class:
      private PrivateClass()
      {
      }

      public static PrivateClass GetPrivateClass()
      {
          //This calls the private constructor so you can control exactly what happens
          return new PrivateClass();
      }

  }
  ```
- [`internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) This means only code in the same assembly (i.e. from inside your library) can access it.

  ```
  public class InternalClass
  {        
      //Only from within the same assembly
      internal InternalClass(string foo)
      {
      }
  }
  ```